# How do I make two observeEvent function for different options in selectinput

Tags: r, shiny

The result page in my program aims to respond differently to the different options the user enters. I feel observeEvent seems relevant but when I wrote this way it only displays the latest observeEvent (which is the female one).

Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Personal Information", 
        selectInput(
          "gender",
          "What is your biological gender?:",
          c("--" = "null","male" = "gender1","female" = "gender2")
        )
      ),
      tabPanel("Result", 
         verbatimTextOutput("result")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
    #Events
    observeEvent(
      {input$gender == "gender1"},
      output$result <- renderPrint ("You are a male.")
    )
    observeEvent(
      {input$gender == "gender2"},
      output$result <- renderPrint ("You are a female.")
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a perfect [MCVE], by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one `observeEvent` that triggers whenever `input$gender` changes. Then have a conditional inside that which determines what value to return. You actually don't need the `observeEvent` at all, since any reactive expression (including a `renderPrint`) will update if any reactive values in it are invalidated. So the best way to do what you want is to replace bout `observeEvent` functions with the below:

```
output$result <- renderPrint({
    if (input$gender == 'gender1') {
        return("You are a male.")
    } else if (input$gender == 'gender2') {
        return("You are a female.")
    }
})
```

The difference with using an `event` function vs a `render*` is that the code block is considered to be in an `isolate` block and only the change of the `eventExpr` will trigger the code to run. That's good if you want to make the code only run when an **Update** button is pressed, but if you want it to be reactive to changing values (like in your example) you shouldn't use an `event` function.

Also, you are strongly encouraged *not* to nest reactive expressions as you do above. If you must have an `event` function drive a `renderPrint` function (as in your example), the reccomended way of doing that is with an `eventReactive`:

```
gender_input <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    if (input$gender == 'gender1') {
        return("You are a male.")
    } else if (input$gender == 'gender2') {
        return("You are a female.")
    }
})

output$result <- renderPrint({gender_input()})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have to use observeEvent instead as there are reactive expressions in my server. Sorry for the underspecification

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. There are always reactive expressions in your server function.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Shiny so I might mess up with the terms... but the point is actually I have an actionbutton so I feel I need that eventReactive as stated in your example. That perfectly works. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help! There's nothing magic about an `actionButton`. When you click the `update` button, all it does is increase the value of the normal reactive value `input$update` by one. So you can use the `inputs` for action buttons in any reactive expression and you can use any `input` or `reactiveValue` as the trigger for an `eventReactive` or `observeEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could place all in 1 observeEvent and depending on the condition, change the desired text and use it then in a renderPrint function like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
  observeEvent(input$gender, {
    if (input$gender == "gender1") {
      txt <- "You are a male."
    } else if (input$gender == "gender2") {
      txt <- "You are a female."
    } else {
      txt <- NULL
    }
    output$result <- renderPrint(txt)
  })
}
```

Allthough i would also favor the solution from @divibisan.

You could although use a reactiveValue, where the text is stored. In this way, you can access the text everywhere in your server function and you dont have to nest the rnderPrint function inside the observeEvent. This is what you would do with the server function:

```
server <- function(input, output) { 

  reactTXT <- reactiveValues(txt=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$gender, {
    if (input$gender == "gender1") {
      txt <- "You are a male."
    } else if (input$gender == "gender2") {
      txt <- "You are a female."
    } else {
      txt <- NULL
    }
    reactTXT$txt <- txt
  })

  output$result <- renderPrint({
    reactTXT$txt
    })
}
```

First you create the reactiveValue `reactTXT`. In the observeEvent you assign the text to the reactiveValue with `reactTXT$txt <- txt`. And in the renderPrint function you just pass the reactiveValue `reactTXT$txt` to print it.

Comment: Thank you! This perfectly works. For some reason, I have to use observeEvent mainly because there are reactive expressions in my server :(